# Jquery Dropdownlist blank first line on load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

When i load my dropdownlist with plain html, the unopened dropdownlist shows the text value for the first option.

But if i load using html or appendTo, the list populates but that unopened list shows no value, it's just blank.

I can see that my problem comes in when i add these 2 essential includes:
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0rc2.min.css
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js

I have set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vauneen/VyfXa/

Can anyone please help me out please?

Thanks in advance,
Vauneen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working.. Check this

html body,

```
<div id="testDiv">
</div>
```

script,

```
var html = '<select   name="selecttwo" id="selecttwo" >';
html += '<option value="1"> 1 </option>';
html += '<option value="2"> 2 </option>';


$('#testDiv').append($(html));
$('#testDiv').trigger('create');
```

Comment: @Vauneen welcome and good to hear that.. cheers ad vote to the  answer

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$("#selecttwo").append($("<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"1\">1</option><option value=\"2\">2</option>"));
$("#selecttwo").append($("("<option  value=\"111\">111</option>1"));



$("#selecttwo").trigger('create');
```

Comment: thanks stay_hungry, but still no luck. the issue is not 'creating' or even ppulating the dropdown. if you look at the fiddle, the list is populated, it just doesnt have an text written on it when it is created (usually a dd either has the selected , or the first option, displayed when it's closed.